# How can I download free apps without registering an Apple ID?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, itunes-store, authentication

> "This Apple ID has not been yet been used before in the iTunes Store. Tap review to sign in, then review your account information."

I keep getting this message when I try to install free apps from App Store. I don't want to give my account info until I actually purchase something.

Can I not download free apps until I provide my account information? My email verification is complete. I'm using an iPhone 3GS logged in to my iTunes account.

Answer (score 14):

This is by design. Apple requires you to [set up an account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141577/this-apple-id-has-not-yet-been-used-with-the-app-store-error) even for free purchases (except podcasts).

In the past, you could set up a free account in iCloud and get away with not entering information, but now the security is getting beefed up.

You may be asked for three security questions and to re-verify your account periodically. The passwords are now more strict in needing a mix of case and numbers where you used to be able to choose a simpler password for your Apple ID.

There are cases where the device is not working properly and you keep getting this verification error, but in the case you describe it is now mandatory to enter more information when setting up your account initially.

Comment: Note that it is possible to set up an account without a credit card, but it requires you to do it in a very specific way.  I did this for my kids phone.

Comment: It always has been possible to make a Store Account without a credit card - but never possible to download without establishing an account / registration of some sort. _(although the process to make a free account has changed slightly over time, and the data required shifts every so often)_

Answer (score 4):

The App Store requires you to have a valid Apple ID (normally an e-mail address) in order to download any content from there.

However, you do not need to add payment methods when following this guide:

[Create an iTunes Store, App Store, or iBooks Store account without a credit card or other payment method](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034)