# 'This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store' error

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

I just got a new macbook pro and I had to set up an Apple ID.

The computer took me through the steps to verify my Apple ID. It says it is verified, but not activated yet. How do I activate it?

When I want to download something from the App Store, it tells me:

> This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store. Please review your account information.

When I click "review" it sends me through this process in which I have to agree to the "Terms and Conditions of the Apple Privacy Policy".

When I click the little box to agree to the terms and conditions, there is nothing left to do. It just sits on the screen and does not allow me to proceed or does not have an option to proceed. What am I supposed to do?

How can I activate my new Apple ID account in order to be able to download from the App Store?

Comment: for some odd reason I can't add an answer. As old as is this question, it's still a nuisance in 2020 so here is what worked for me:  1. On the ipad in question, logged out of itunes account: click Cancel on the pop-up, click the user icon on up-left and sign out. 2. Re-login with the same account. I'm being now presented with "agree to T&S" form. That's it! I've wasted 2h on this, what a bad design.

Comment: The working solutions is : 1. Click your profile image is appStore. 2. Sign out from your account. 3. Login again, this time this will show you the same message, 4. click on Review button, 5. boom... now you can agree to the term & conditions 6. Finally relogin, everything will work fine. thank me later

Comment: The registration of AppleID requires the network used for Internet connection to be of the same region as you AppleID account is. Try to use different internet connection for AppStore activation. Once you successfully activated your account you may use Internet connection whatever you want.

Comment: I signed out and then signed in again. That worked.

Answer (score 45):

The resolution for me was to launch iTunes on my Mac (Music app on Big Sur and later), and sign in from the account menu there.

Have some patience and keep trying if it at first does nothing; I had to log in twice as clicking on the "Review" button on the first attempt did nothing.

I had to accept the terms of service and reenter my payment details, even though I had already done both these things from signing in to the Apple ID website.

In the final step of the log in wizard, I received an error message, but it appeared that nevertheless iTunes was logged in. I could then exit iTunes and launch the App Store, and I was prompted three times to log in, but I no longer received the error message instructing me to review my account information.

It seems that the third time was a charm, because it then displayed a welcome message. When you are signing up on a big day for server traffic, check the store status for outages as well: https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

(Cue here the obligatory grumble about this being an atrocious experience.)

Comment: thanks yes, the secret to get out of this loop is to launch itunes on the mac and sign in again - what a mess

Comment: Indeed. The AppStore app on the Mac was only giving the loop and didn't offer any screen to confirm the details.

The iTunes app didn't exist anymore on Big Sur (11.5) but the Apple Music app worked for me. Showed a screen offering to confirm the country and the payment data I had already added on the web.

After that wizard finished, the AppStore app was able to log in.



Comment: Looks like Apple Music and Apple TV apps will let you sign in and break the bug in the App Store sign in flow. Truely awful experience from Apple.

Comment: I have successfully login in Apple TV application and after that was able to log in App Store application. Looks like apple engineers have good skills in leetcode, know how to pass 10-steps interview, but forgot how to code well.

Comment: Yup, this is the one. It looks like some kind of data normalization problem. The payment and shipping info needs to be confirmed in the music store first, otherwise the app store will ask for it and enter the infinite loop. What a horrible misfeature. Maybe Apple doesn't expect a new user to update their apps first thing after booting ...

Comment: This is still a problem in 2021. I was stuck in the `This Apple ID has not yet been used in the iTunes store` infinite loop on my iPhone. I fixed it by using the App Store on my MacBook. I installed a free app (as I prefer not to give Apple a credit card) on the laptop and it asked me to log in and accept the Terms & Conditions. After that I was able to install apps on the iPhone.

Comment: This was what solve it for me, This seems like a glaring issue that Apple should pay some attention to, even if it's just providing some details to the user on WHY it's failing instead of being stuck in a login loop

Comment: I am on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559). Signing in from apple's "Music" app worked for free. Although initially, I was not able to find the sign-in option anywhere in the "Music" app. Then I noticed that you have to click the "Try It Free" button on the "Listen Now" tab. Then a modal with the title "Get 3 months of free music" is shown. Click again on the "Try it Free" button in that modal. Then you will be shown the modal to enter apple id. Adding apple id and password there, and then confirming terms and conditions, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 31):

I faced same problem (the infinite loop) when trying to download app from App Store on my iPhone XS (iOS 14.6). I guess there's a bug to continue the process on mobile.

So I decided to try it on my Macbook and it worked!

My solution is to open TV app on mac then follow the process below:

1. Open TV app on Mac
2. Click Sign In menu
3. You'll get same error like on mobile. Click Review.
4. Fill your apple ID
5. Continue the process until finish.

[image]

[image]

Comment: On an IPhone SE in the Music app, I clicked on the circle icon with a person in the top right corner.  Then I went through the prompts.  When asked for a credit card, I paused and saw somewhere I could choose no payment.

I also did the other suggestion of setting up a credit card and address for the AppleID on their web site, but I am unsure this was necessary.

Comment: This one worked for me (Big Sur 11.5.1)

Comment: This is the only one that works

Comment: This is the only method I've found that actually works. If you're already logged in to Apple TV, click Account > Signout, and then sign back in

Answer (score 25):

If you've just created a new Apple ID, and it is giving you the message "This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store", it is because :

1. The **payment details are not added**, please check that you have entered a valid credit/ debit card in the payment section in the below mentioned link, then try.
2. After entering the payment details then **sign out from your device and then try again** to login, try until you get the welcome page.

Login to [appleid](https://appleid.apple.com), go to "Payment & Shipping" and set your address for both Billing and Shipping and enter the details.
I think this helps to get out of that cycle.

Comment: This actually does not work, adding the address to payments and shipping does not fix the issue

Comment: This fixed an infinite loop of password requests in the itunes store.

Comment: Billing/shipping address + credit card details had to be added, for me to get out of the infinite loop.

Comment: +1 If the dialog you are seeing after clicking "Review", asks for an AppleID and password, but only offers a password box without displaying your ID or offering a place to type your ID, account setup is not complete. Your AppleID MUST be present in the dialog text, or it will just keep showing you the same request over and over again.

Comment: what if it's a child account and you don't want to setup payment for a minor? Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: This worked, but I had to completely quit the AppStore, re-open it, and then click "Sign in" on the bottom right to finish the process and accept all the terms.

Comment: I added all that information, but it didn't work for me as well and still got this infinite loop. Based on one article that I found I signed out from my Apple ID on device and signed in again. Then everything worked like a charm!

Comment: This did not work for me, but [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378455/8349) worked (sign in from the Music app)

Comment: I simply logged in through iTunes, selected "My Account," agreed to the terms of service and filled in my address WITHOUT any payment information. Apple's system then allowed me to log in to the App Store.

Answer (score 6):

Did you receive a verification email at the email address you set up as your AppleID?  If not, log into https://appleid.apple.com using the email and the password you created. In there, you should have options on the screen to verify the email address if it is not already verified.

Comment: this does not work either

Comment: What worked for me was to go to settings, I saw Media and Purchases was not switched on. I switched it on. Only then was I able to review and accept the conditions in order to use all the apple services.