# Apple App Store Sign in loop (Mac Appstore)

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

Whenever I try to sign in using my Apple ID it says "This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store." and asks me to review my account info I click review and then it asks me to sign in again then it again says "This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store." I sign in again its an endless loop.

Can someone pls help me I need to download Xcode

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! Have you checked other questions with this error message, e.g. ['This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store' error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/141577/121968)?

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't solve my problems i.e. it keeps doing the loop, plus I am -18 but +13 so I don't have a bank account either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem on Macbook Pro (2019) (runs on Monterey) as steps below:

1. Completely sign out Apple ID in local machine (specifically iCloud).
2. `⌘ + Space` to search `Music`.
3. Run `Music`.
4. Click on `Account` from topbar and click `Sign In` option.
5. Login your credentials and then Terms & Conditions page will be shown up.

**Note:** If any information requiring by application like payment method, billing address or etc. (**Security Code** or **Expiration Date** informations can be blank inputs on this stage, even if you confirmed on [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com).) fill them.

**Note 2:** Be sure your credit card is open to online shopping, Apple sends a test request to validate.