# Installing Google Maps without an Apple ID?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to install Google Maps without an Apple ID?

Answer (score 3):

[No](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49951/how-can-i-download-free-apps-without-registering-an-apple-idcool), Apple requires that–for apps on iOS from the App Store–you register for an Apple ID. This is by design, so you must create an Apple ID if you wish to download any app.

Comment: Would have been better to just flag as dupe, imo.

Comment: :/ yeah probably.